# Get only one parameter from json object via retrofit(gson)

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

Json:

[image: JSON]

I need to get only id field from source. Data class:

```
data class Article(
    val sourceId: String,
    val author: String,
    val title: String,
    ...
)
```

Convertor factory is GsonConvertorFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON you provided, `source` is a complex object, so you can't define it as a string unless you create a [custom deserialiser](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization). A quick way to get this working, though, is to create another set of classes to mimic the JSON structure, like this:

```
data class Source(
        val id: String
)

data class Article(
        val source: Source,
        val author: String,
        val title: String
)
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
fun main() {
    val json = """ {
    "source": {
      "id": "bbc-news",
      "name": "BBC News"
    },
    "author": "BBC News",
    "title": "Afrobeat pioneer Tony Allen dies aged 79"
}
""".trimIndent()

    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

    val article = gson.fromJson(json, Article::class.java)
    println(article)
}
```

This prints: `Article(source=Source(id=bbc-news), author=BBC News, title=Afrobeat pioneer Tony Allen dies aged 79)`.